# Let $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphsim. Then $\operatorname{Int} \phi^*(Y_{\phi(f)})=X_f$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

> Statement (False) : Let $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphsim , $\phi^*: \text{Spec}(B) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(A)$. Also, $\operatorname{Int}$ is a topological interior set and for $f \in A$ , $X_f:=\{ \mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec} : f \notin \mathfrak{p} \} $.
> Then, is it true  $\operatorname{Int}( \phi^*(Y_{\phi(f)}))=X_f$ ,where $X=\text{Spec}(A) , Y=\text{Spec}(B)$ ?

[Question] Is it true? If it is false, is there some true statements which is associated with image $\phi^*$ of open set?

---

[Motivation]

I know that three facts as followings

(i) For $f \in A$, $ {\phi^*}^{-1}(X_f)=Y_{\phi{(f)}}$ .

(ii) For an ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $A$,  ${\phi^*}^{-1}(V(\mathfrak{a}))=V(\mathfrak{a}B)$ ,where $V(\mathfrak{a}) := \{ \mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec} :  \mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{p} \} $

(iii) For an ideal $\mathfrak{b}$ of $B$,  $\overline{{\phi^*}(V(\mathfrak{b}))}=V({\phi}^{-1}(\mathfrak{b}))$

Since for $f \in A$ , $X_f$ is a basic open set, (i) is associated with the inverse image of open sets.

Also, (ii) , (iii) are associated with the image and inverse image of closed sets.

I hope that there is a statement of image $\phi^*$ of open sets.

---

[EDIT]

By comment of KReiser, I see now above statement is false. In fact, take $A=k[x,y]$ , $B=^{k[x,y]}/ _{(y)}$ , $f=1$ , $\phi:A \rightarrow B$ is a natural projection map . Then, take natural mapping ${\phi}^* : \mathbb{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ and Im ${\phi}^*$= $V((y))$ , so $\operatorname{Int} (\text{Im} {\phi}^*) = \operatorname{Int} ({\phi}^*(Y_{\phi(1)})) = \emptyset $

However, I hope to find a true statement related to  $\phi^*(Y_{\phi(f)})$

Comment: Maybe try looking in the exercises of Atiyah-Macdonald chapter III.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Sorry , I can't find.  I think there is no problem related to this in chapter III.

Comment: This is kind of hard to read right now since you're mixing $X,Y$ and $\operatorname{Spec} A,\operatorname{Spec} B$ without explicitly saying which is which. Anyways, assuming I'm not reading it wrong, this is trivially false: consider $\Bbb A^1\to \Bbb A^2$ in the obvious fashion. The interior of the image of $\Bbb A^1$ is empty. What's your goal here? Do you need this statement for some other problem?

Comment: @KReiser Nice ! Thank you for your comment and edit. I see now this is a false statement. My actual goal is finding a true statement associated with open image of ${\phi}^*$

Comment: That's very vague. Why do you hope this? Is there some specific problem you're trying to solve here? MSE works best when addressing specific questions, and without a clear and specific goal in mind your post may be unsuitable for this website.

Comment: @KReiser I already write the motivation above.. I think meaning of question is clear. Why do you think it is very vague? Since there is statements of image and preimage of $\phi^*$ of closed sets, I wonder if there is statement of open set.  It is a very natural question .